# Will the delete function be triggered if on_delete is set to models.PROTECT?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to implement a behavior where when I am trying to delete an instance, the instance will not be deleted but django will set an attribute called `deleted` to `True`.

However, when I am trying to define a foreign key, I have to set `on_delete` because it is required. I set it to `models.PROTECT`. My question is: Will django trigger my overridden `delete` function while setting `on_delete` to `models.PROTECT`?

Here is an example code:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
  deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
    self.deleted = True
    self.save()


class A(BaseModel):
  pass


class B(BaseModel):
  a = models.ForeignKey('A', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Comment: No since the logic of the collector, etc. is implemented in the `delete` function of the `Model`. Since you do not make a `super()` call, the logic will not be triggered.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Won't calling `super().delete()` leads to deleting the instance from the DB?

Comment: exactly. But you here "soft delete" it. Hence the object should not be deleted from the database. You could consider `django-soft-delete`, which already implements such functionality https://github.com/scoursen/django-softdelete

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think the answer should be yes based on what I understood from your answer. My question is: Will django call the overridden `delete` function that I wrote in the `BaseModel`? or will django raise an exception because of setting `on_delete` to `models.PROTECT` and not calling the `delete` function?